# Regular expression for pattern XX.XX.XX. where X is any number 0-9?

Tags: r, regex

This is probably a simple question but I don't have much experience with regular expressions and I can't figure it out on my own. I have tried putting together the expression based on cheat sheets but none have come close to working apart from this one `[0-9.0-9\\.0-9.0-9\\.0-9.0-9\\.]`, but this one also let through a wrong string.

Basically I want to check if all rows in certain columns follow that pattern exactly (that is, there are no other characters) so I can correct those cells which don't and then do further manipulations. Some examples of matching strings would be `01.12.20.` or `26.02.11.`, and some that don't match would be `01.12.20`, `26.0.2.11.` etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more economical regex, that will also catch entries with incorrect leading or trailing entries would be

```r
grep("^(\\d{2}\\.){3}$", str)
```

To find the entries that *don't* match the pattern (as described in the question) we could do:

```r
str <- c("01.12.20.",  "26.02.11.", "01.12.20,", "26.0.2.11.")

grep("^(\\d{2}\\.){3}$", str, invert = TRUE)
#> [1] 3 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the pattern that you want:

```
[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.
```

Comment: Wouldn't this incorrectly identify strings with leading or trailing junk as being OK? For example `6098701.12.20.aaa`